# How to stop DLL Hijacking for secondary IMPLICITLY loaded DLLs

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, mfc

For example, COMDLG32.DLL implicitly links against the following system DLLs (among others):
xmllite.dll
msftedit.dll
srvcli.dll
wkscli.dll
linkinfo.dll
netutils.dll
msi.dll

Since these are implicitly loaded by the operating system, not explicitly loaded using LoadLibrary call, the hijack vulnerability workaround using `SetDllDirectory` does not affect these loads being done when COMDLG32.DLL is loaded.

Hence, after my application is loaded, and I hit Ctrl+O to use the File Open dialog, these "bad" DLLs (that exist in my EXE's folder) get loaded.

COMDLG32.DLL is loading the ones in my EXE folder, not the legitimate ones in the system folder, even though I am calling `SetDllDirectory("");` in `InitInstace()` long before I launch the File Open dialog.

How can I get a system DLL (e.g. COMDLG32.DLL) to properly utilize the correct DLL for its implicitly loaded DLLs?

Comment: Using an installer to correctly install your program (under program files) will  set the directory permissions to not allow new files to be created in that directory.  These permissions can obviously be changed by someone with admin access; but then we are on the other side of the airtight hatch (admin access) and they could just replace your entire program.

Comment: You are over overthinking this. If the attacker is free to perform this hijacking, why would they bother? It's a painfully laborious way to do I'll deeds. Install the program properly as Richard says.

Comment: @RichardCritten @DavidHeffernan What is the purpose of `SetDllDirectory` then?  I thought it was to mitigate this issue?

Comment: @franji1 To break windows security: _"The SetDllDirectory function affects all subsequent calls to the LoadLibrary and LoadLibraryEx functions. It also effectively __disables safe DLL search mode__ while the specified directory is in the search path."_  (my bold) source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten I believe that only applies when the parameter is an actual path, not "". The point is moot because the question is about the application directory, not the current directory.

Comment: There is no issue to mitigate. There is no problem to be solved.

Comment: (a) [Dubious security vulnerability: Attacking the application directory in order to fool yourself?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161013-00/?p=94505) (b) [It rather involved being on the other side of this airtight hatchway: Writing to the application directory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121207-00/?p=5893)(c) [It rather involved being on the other side of this airtight hatchway: Open access to the application directory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130802-00/?p=3633) and...

Comment: (d) [In Windows, the directory is the application bundle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110620-00/?p=10393)

Comment: @conio But [“the application directory is considered a trusted location” the exception to this is the Downloads folder.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161013-00/?p=94505#comment-1268645) - I bet many installers are vulnerable to DLL hijacking. WiX for instance recently implemented [some measures](http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/5184-burn-clean-room/) against that.

Comment: Is your program - the one with the File Open dialog... - an installer?

Comment: @conio - no.  It is an MFC application.  We are dealing with the DLL hijacking issue in multiple scenarios, one of which is a "bad" DLL with the same name as a system DLL that is used by COMDLG32.DLL (see the list above).  We have a similar issue with the MFC DLL implicit DLL dependency with OTHER system DLLs, but I wanted to address the (VERY delay loaded) "bad" DLL via the File Open dialog, which occurs after the app has fully loaded.

Comment: @franji1: Then [In Windows, the directory is the application bundle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110620-00/?p=10393), etc. (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161013-00/?p=94505 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121207-00/?p=5893 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130802-00/?p=3633)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SetDllDirectory("")` removes the current/working directory from the DLL search path, it does **not** have any effect on the application directory (where your .exe is located).

You can call [`SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310515(v=vs.85).aspx) if you want to limit yourself to the system32 directory.

Comment: I know we are peeling an onion here.  Where can I call `SetDefaultDllDirectories` early enough such that any implicitly linked system DLLs are properly loaded when my EXE loads?  My `InitInstance()`?  By then, if it's a system DLL that needs to load immediately (due to a dependency of MFC DLL, for example), my `InitInstance()` call may be too late.

Comment: For whatever reason there is no entry you can add to the .manifest to apply this setting before WinMain. ComDlg32 is on the KnownDlls list so it (and whatever it links to) should load from system32 if you link to it in your import table (LoadLibrary does not respect that list). Did you actually test to see if the wrong dlls are loaded on a real system?

Comment: @franji1, it isn't clear to me whether you understand that DLL hijacking *by DLLs in the application directory* isn't a security vulnerability.  It is only a security vulnerability when the wrong DLL is loaded from the *current* directory, and I don't think that happens in your scenario.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I am purposefully putting "hijacked" DLLs (these just put up a message box in DLLMain) with the same name as system DLLs in my application's folder (see the DLL list in my question).  These are DLLs that are IMPLICITLY loaded by the "correct" COMDLG32.DLL.  So, these "hijacked" DLLs are NOT in the CWD, but in the EXE folder.

Comment: Yep.  And in that scenario, Windows is perfectly entitled to load the DLLs you've provided instead of the system ones.  If you didn't want it to do so, you wouldn't have put them there, right?

Comment: @Anders - yes.  I have a "stub" of a "hijacked" DLL that all it does is bring up a MessageBox in DLLMain.  I just copy the same DLL to all of the System DLL file names in my question.  After launching my app, I hit Ctrl+O to bring up the (common) Open File dialog, and as the COMDLG32.DLL starts loading, these implicitly linked files load my "stub-hijacked" DLLs located in my EXE's folder, instead of the actual ones in the System folder.  Note that COMDLG32.DLL is NOT hijacked - it's loading from the Sys folder correctly, but it is loading the implicitly linked "stub-hijacked" DLLs.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Just trying to make our app more "bullet proof" regarding "hijacked" DLLs (or whatever this scenario is called).

Comment: There's no point.  If someone could put malicious DLLs into your application directory, they could equally well replace the executable with a malicious one.  See, for example, [Open access to the application directory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130802-00/?p=3633) on The Old New Thing.  "Hijacked DLLs" is when a DLL is loaded from the *current directory*, there's no name for the scenario when a DLL is loaded from the application directory.  We could invent one if you like, how about the "way it's supposed to work" scenario? :-)

Comment: ... now, a downloadable installer is a special case, but from what you've said so far that's not what you're dealing with.

Comment: Program Files security, `SetDllDirectory("")` work as described.  `SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32)` solved the specific issue with File Open dialog, but caused other issue on future fully qualified path LoadLibrary calls (LoadLibrary failed unless it was a system DLL in the system folder; DLL file name was fully qualified to EXE folder, but failed; in debug window, LoadLibrary call said it loaded, then immediately unloaded, then LoadLibrary returned 0).

Comment: I think you can try LoadLibraryEx with the alternate search flag or manually whitelist with AddDllDirectory. Or you can use LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR or LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR.