# How can I control search order for DLLs to avoid hijacking?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dllimport

As a background: my application requires:

- admin privileges
- access to WinAPI DLLs
- be able to run on all OSs: Win7-Win10

Normally, to use API, I can just link required *.lib files. However it uses default search order, that means (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) it firstly loads DLLs from "The directory from which the application loaded."
As a result, if the DLL exists in the same directory, running my app by double-click loads also that DLL.
I want to look for DLLs only in system directories (similarly to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46182665/9015013 ).

I know I can try to create some kind of proxy, like

```
    BOOL WinAPIFunction(WinAPIType param) {
  return reinterpret_cast<decltype(&WinAPIFunction)>(
    reinterpret_cast<void*>(GetProcAddress(manually_loaded_module, "WinAPIFunction")))(param);
}
```

But it is hard to maintain all these functions. Is there any better method to force windows to look only in system32? I thought about manifest file but it requires version for each DLL that can break "capability" requirement (DLLs have different version for Win7 and Win10)

Comment: Why do you feel it is your responsibility to avoid such hijacking?

Comment: Users may "trust" my app and I want to be sure it cannot be use to take control on users' machine. I'm not sure if average user is aware about DLL hijacking.

Comment: Who do you imagine is going to be hijacking DLLs? How are they going to gain write access to the program files folder where your program is installed?

Comment: My app is not installed, that is an issue. I can imagine situation:
1. Download malicious DLL (accidentally)
2. Download my app
3. Run my app with admin privileges

Comment: Install your program to the program files directory and that would require any attacker to gain admin rights to modify your installation. If you are asking the user to run your app from the downloads directory then that's your real mistake. Fix the real problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: my app is some kind of installer so it doesn't make any sense to install installer only to install sth else. But the problem is wider, not all ppl wants to install anything on their OS only to do one thing - easier is just run than download-install-run-uninstall.

Comment: That makes more sense. But if you want to make a decent installer, build and msi package. And if you really do want to avoid the scenario you describe, just have the program that is downloaded unpack to a temp directory that you create when your downloaded program runs. Once unpacked, run the unpacked program from that directory which you control. In other words, solve the problem the right way by not running your code from an insecure directory.

Comment: You could [delay load](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2019) the DLLs. Then, if [`SetDefaultDllDirectories`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories) is available by way of `GetProcAddress` (at least Windows Vista w/ KB2533623), set up the DLL search path at startup to include "%SystemRoot%\System32" (e.g. "C:\Windows\System32"), and exclude the application directory. This also excludes the current directory ("."), "%SystemRoot%", "%SystemRoot%\System", and `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is posted by @Eryk Sun in comment above.

It is sufficient to add all DLLs not listed in known dlls to delayed loaded libraries and call SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32); at the beginning of the WinMain.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "Known DLLs" feature: If Windows "knows" that DLL, Windows doesn't search dll file. Known feature is described into link, you written in question.

Comment: It is a list of "known" DLLs, I cannot modify it or interact with it anyhow :(

Comment: Why would you need to modify this list. Surely it contains all the system DLLs?

Comment: No, it doesn't contain all of them. I want to use e.g. userenv.dll or cabinet.dll

Comment: There are some methods for changing registry (internet will help you). One of strange method is to load from rescue disk and change registry value or security from external utility. Sorry, but you want strange things and you can do it by strange ways.

Comment: @Evgeny: but it solves issue from "admin" perspective. I want to solve it from my exe (prevent loading DLLs from "untrusted" location).

Comment: A non-system installer should not modify the system's private list of known DLLs. Doing this would also require rebooting. The known DLLs list is prepared at startup. The corresponding registry key is used to initialize an object directory of named Section objects (file mappings) for the DLLs. The registry key is not referenced dynamically.