# Is there any way to specify the dll search path of windows system for a win32 com program?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have made a win32 com application which need to be run as admin. It will load some system symbols (e.g. MSASN1.dll).
Currenly, it will first search MSASN1.dll in installation path (e.g. %Appdata%\MyComProgram). If not found, then it will continue to search MSASN1.dll in system path (e.g. %SystemRoot%\system32)
I wonder if there is any way to let the program search system dll in system path first and then search installation path.

I have searched the MSDN and have read the pages
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/LibLoaderAPI/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya

It seems the ways in MSDN are for dll loaded by explicitly calling LoadLibrary. But the system dlls loaded in my program are more like a part of COM server, not be explicitly called.

I have read the way in [How can I control search order for DLLs to avoid hijacking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59818651/how-can-i-control-search-order-for-dlls-to-avoid-hijacking). Yes, delay load the DLLs can work, but it will cause other issues in my application.

I wonder if there is any way to let the program search system dll in system path first and then search installation path.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would have expected the system to favor system locations for executable images, with [Dynamic-link library redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-redirection) allowing to override this. It sounds like what you're observing doesn't follow the rules spelled out in the link. Can you share how you've verified this? Also, the procedure you're trying to control is commonly called *"load time dynamic linking"* (as opposed to *"run time dynamic linking"*).

Comment: @IInspectable I use process monitor to check where did the program load dll symbols.

Comment: As Dynamic-link library redirection doc said, "the DLL loader looks in the folder that the calling process was loaded from (the executable's folder) before it looks in other file system locations." It seems to be the same as what I found.

Comment: *dll symbols* - what you mean under this ?

Comment: @RbMm Just dll files. For example, MSASN1.dll

Comment: this is wrong term in this case . symbols - this is pdb file. absolute another thing

Comment: @IInspectable Let me correct my comments. I used Process Monitor to track Load Image operation. I put a MSASN1.dll in the installation path of my program and found it was loaded by my program.

Comment: You have very little control over where statically-linked DLLs are loaded from at process startup. Your code is not running yet when those DLLs are loaded, so you can't influence the search path. You have more control over where DLLs are loaded from if you load them dynamically at runtime via `LoadLibrary/Ex()` - whether you call it explicitly or use your linker's *delay-load* feature (which uses `LoadLibrary()` internally). That allows you to configure the search path before they are loaded.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, as you said. But changing these statically-linked DLLs to delay-loaded will cause other issues. Currently, this COM program was launched by ShellExecute from another program also made by us. I can also change code in that program before ShellExecute. Are there any ways? Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked [Standard search order for unpackaged apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-unpackaged-apps)? And the more formal way is [Using SignTool to Sign a File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/using-signtool-to-sign-a-file).

Comment: I'm not aware of any functional differences between load time dynamic linking and use of the delay-load linker support to resolve static imports. If you are running into issues, then that would make for a good question.